# How to move focus and perform validations using jquery from one field to another field by pressing enter key?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

Need help.

We are migrating a legacy application (developed in 3GL language) to ASP.NET MVC4.  The client wants similar behavior of the application in the web.  There are more than 25 fields are available in a form and focus moves from one field to another fields on press enter key. The legacy application fires a validation (invokes flat files and compares values and throws error message) on pressing enter key on each fields.

Is it possible to achieve the same behavior in web using jquery validate in combination of ajax call to controller for validation on press of enter key? Any suggestions/reference patterns to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use javascript and subscribe to the `onkeypress` event of all input fields and if the key is enter move to the next field. As far as validation is concerned, you could still use the jquery unobtrusive validation which comes out of the box in MVC and will be triggered `onblur` (when the cursor leaves the current input field). All you have to do is decorate your view model properties with the corresponding Data Annotations (`[Required]`, ...) and include the `jquery`, `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` scripts to your page (in that order).

Let's have an example:

As always you start with a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [MinLength(5)]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // TODO: the input is valid => process it here

        return Content("success");
    }
}
```

and the corresponding view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Foo)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Foo)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Bar)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Bar)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Bar)
    </div>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Set the focus to the first input element initially
    $('form input:first').focus();

    // enable eager client side validation without requiring the form to be submitted
    $(function () {
        var settings = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
        settings.onfocusout = function (element) { $(element).valid(); };
    });

    // subscribe to the keypress event of the input fields in order to move
    // the focus to the next field
    $('input, select, textarea').keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).closest('div').next('div').find(':first-child').focus();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply Darin. I have below issues while running your code. in IE 11, it throws error 'Unable to get property 'settings' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply Darin.  I have below issues while running your code. 
in IE 11, it throws error 'Unable to get property 'settings' of undefined or null reference.
In Chrome(31.0.1650.63m) ,  it did not trigger the validation on pressing enter key.  i can able to move out from Foo Field to Bar field without entering any values.   
The requirement is, it should not move out to other field until user enters the correct value.   The users will use enter key or tab out for navigation between fields.

Comment: In this case you could improve the script to meet those requirements. Don't just wait for me writing all the code. I've already put you onto the right track. StackOverflow is not a place where you would just put your requirements and expect people writing code for you. In case you encounter some specific problems attempting to implement those requirements don't hesitate to show your progress and you might get more help.